# Is there a datetimepicker class in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, datetimepicker, xamarin.forms

I am currently using the Xamarin Forms `DatePicker` and the `TimePicker` in the portable project of a portable app. But is there a combined control that lets you choose date and time at once (like DateTimePicker in Windows forms)? Please have a look at the iOS Settings > General > Date & Time (http://www.iphonefaq.org/images/archives/pangu-date.jpg).

Or is there anything I am missing on how to create such a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a "stock" `DateTimePicker` within the controls for `Xamarin.Forms`.

You could create your composite control using `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` within modal popups and display the `Date` & `Time` chosen in `Label`s...

Or create your own Form control using custom renders:

- [Customizing Controls on Each Platform](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)
- [Xamarin.Forms Widget/Control Listing](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/views/)

Comment: That's sad, so sad